# Chromium Logo Invisible

Tags: launcher, chromium, logo

I installed Chromium yesterday from the Software centre.After installation I searched for it in the dash and then dragged that logo to the Launcher. The other logos rightly moved up/down but the Logo of Chromium is invisible. When I click on the empty space in the launcher,chromium does launch without any trouble(works all right as well) but the fact that I cant see the logo means there is some issue.

Has anyone else faced this problem as I tried searching for it but couldn't find anything.

Please help

Comment: I had that problem with Audacity. Dragging it from the dash to the launcher gave a blank space which did open Audacity when clicked. I removed this "ghost" from the launcher and then ran Audacity by clicking its icon in the dash. That caused its icon to be visible in the launcher. Then, I right-clicked and chose "keep in launcher". That gave a visible icon.

Comment: This issue is most likely due to the following bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/772986

Answer (score 1):

Try logging out and back in, or if that doesn't work then try a reboot. I had a similar issue with GTK-Recordmydesktop.