# I have an invisible icon in my launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I created a desktop shortcut using this command:

```
 `gnome-desktop-item-edit –create-new ~/Desktop`
```

Then I thought it would be a great idea to see if I can drag the icon onto the launcher. I tried twice in order to manage. Unfortunately now I have the icon I wanted originally, plus an empty space onto my launcher which, when I rollover, says  "Drop to add application". I removed the original icon, but the empty space remains. BTW, nothing happens when I click on the empty space.

Ah, this is the first time I am using Ubuntu, I fell in love with it, but now I have a feeling my new operating system is too fragile to play around with, and even worse, I get a feeling of helplessness :) Complex feelings associated with an OS:)

Please help, I would hate to have to reinstall the whole think again!

Comment: Can you add a screen shot? it may help

Comment: Ah, I fixed it! I did this: unity-reset and it, well... reset the launcher (along with other bits I assume, but I am not concerned with those:))

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
unity --replace
```

in terminal. If that doesn't work, you can reset it using

```
unity --reset
```

Comment: Just an FYI - `unity --reset` is now deprecated and should not be used. Taken from `unity --help`: `Reset is not supported anymore. Deprecated option`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question :

["invisible" icons in the launcher bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91865/invisible-icons-in-the-launcher-bar)

Try to find your answer

Comment: Unfortunately my answer was not in other. I had checked that one before posting my question. But I fixed my problem by doing unity-reset in the terminal!

Answer (score 0):

I solved running

```
unity --reset-icons
```

but it will close most of your running apps, so close them prior to execute.